# How can I find where SSLv2 is still being used? (nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl

**Edit**: I am unable to connect to the server explicitly with SSLv2 on port 443, yet drownattack.com and ssllabs are both reporting the server is still vulnerable on port 443.

I'm trying to resolve the DROWN vulnerability on a server and it appears that a service is still using SSLv2. `lsof` shows that only nginx is using port 443, but I have only TSLv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 enabled in nginx.conf, as well as each of the vhost configuration files. Where else can I look, or is there a tool available for me to tell exactly where SSLv2 is still being used on the server?

Relevant nginx.conf section:

```
http {

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

Comment: Start with what service appears to still be using SSLv2? Where did you get this information?

Comment: Drownattack.com reports port 443 as vulnerable to DROWN, and lsof shows only nginx running on port 443, however I do not have SSLv2 enabled in nginx.conf

Comment: Show us the relevant bits of your nginx config.

Comment: @ceejayoz edited in the OP

Comment: @Morgan You've restarted nginx since this config? Can you share your domain for us to take a look?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes I have. And unfortunately I cannot share the domain as it belongs to a client, not myself.

Comment: See if https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html shows you as vulnerable.

Comment: @ceejayoz It does indeed.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your server using 'openssl s_client'? I'm curious if it shows SSLv2 as supported in the handshake. If so, it might be that nginx isn't getting those settings disabled for some reason

Comment: @BobTuckerman what exactly am I looking for in the response from `openssl s_client`?

Comment: From memory I thought it listed the TLS / SSL versions, but I may have been mistaken. Try connecting with the '-ssl2' flag and see if it connects. Or try the nmap approach described here. http://security.stackexchange.com/a/70737

Comment: @BobTuckerman I attempted to connect explicitly via SSL2 and the connection did not work. Additionally, I've noticed that the Qualys SSL labs report notes that SSL2 is not available, yet still claims the server is vulnerable to the DROWN attack.

Comment: I think you're mis-understanding what the Drown Test does. It doesn't mean that the server/url you are testing is using SSL2, it just means another server is using SSL2 with the same certificate RSA Key. https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2016/03/04/ssl-labs-drown-test-implementation-details

Comment: @Drifter104 You're absolutely right, I was misunderstanding. I thought just disabling SSLv2 would fix it, thank you!